# Extract numbers from response in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-re

when i send request to the server i will receive this response

```
{"SUBMIT_FLAG":1,"BALANCE":"  412000  "}
```

how can i extract just last numbers 412000 this is numbers its variable
and sorry for my bad language
thanks in advance

Comment: Is it always under `BALANCE` ? What about the position of the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the json module like this:

```
import json

data = """
{"SUBMIT_FLAG":1,"BALANCE":"  412000  "}
"""

json_data = json.loads(data)

print(json_data['BALANCE'])
```

**Output**

```
412000
```